# rearrange an input that result must have alternating sequence of odd and even numbers

Tags: c++

I am looking for an **stable algorithm** for rearranging the array to alternate even and odd numbers

example:
Input: `{2, 8, 9 ,10 ,14 ,17 ,21, 13, 97};`

Output: `9  2  17  8  21  10  13  14  97`
because odd number are more than even numbers so sequencing started from first odd number 9;
also print some error message if alternate rearrangement is not possible; e.g. if some input has too much even numbers and there are not sufficient odd numbers and vice versa;

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a homework shopping mall, you must have misunderstood something.

Comment: This question is a little broad. If you constrain it to where there are an equal number of odd and even elements, I think it's sufficiently narrow to be reopened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is modified version of [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-odd-and-even-values-in-alternate-fashion-in-ascending-order/)

Below is the solution; this might work:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> ip = {2, 8, 9 ,10 ,14 ,17 ,21, 13, 97};
    std::vector<int> even, odd;
    for(const auto& num: ip)
        num%2 == 0 ? even.emplace_back(num) : odd.emplace_back(num); // emplace_back inserts in end maintaing stability
    if(abs(even.size() - odd.size()) >1)
    {
        std::cout<< "\n alternate sequence not possible";
        return 0;
    }
    auto& max = even.size() >= odd.size() ? even : odd;
    auto& min = max == even ? odd : even;
    ip.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i< (int)min.size();i++)
    {
        ip.push_back(max[i]);
        ip.push_back(min[i]);
    }
    if(max.size()> min.size())
        ip.push_back(*(max.end()-1));

    for(const auto& num: ip)
        std::cout<<"  "<< num;
    return 0;
}
```